# The method toJson(...) is undefined for the type Gson

Tags: java, json, serialization, jar, gson

I'm trying to serialize Java Nested Object into Json format using GSON library for my project. I've downloaded gson-2.8.2.jar and built a path.

- Is there anything else I have to do for this jar to work properly? 
  I've heard people mentioning Maven, but I'm not familiar with it at all and it seems quite complicated for my level of programming skills.
- I get a "*The method toJson(ParentObject) is undefined for the type Gson*" error. I've read a tonne of info on generic/non-generic types, but it still is hard to understand. I tried to call "*.toJson(Object src, Type typeOfSrc)*", but I can't get the Type right.  Should I use this method and what should I write in "Type"?
- There seems to be something wrong with my array too. I tried to print it, but keep getting an "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException" error. Does anybody know why it might be happening?

This is my main java class:

```
package Gson_package;
import com.google.gson.*;

public class Gson {
public static void main(String args[]) {
ParentObject obj1 = new ParentObject();
serializeJson(obj1);
}

public static String serializeJson(ParentObject obj1) {     
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(obj1);
return json;
}}
```

This is my Parent Class that creates an array, with another nested class that creates objects with two properties:

```
package Gson_package;

public class ParentObject {
public Property [] myArray; //1 attribute - An array of "Property" Objects

public ParentObject() //Default constructor {
for(int i = 0;i<9;i++){
myArray[i] = new Property("", "");
}
myArray[0].setPropertyValue("firstname", "HubSpot");
myArray[1].setPropertyValue("lastname", "Test");
myArray[2].setPropertyValue("website", "http://hubspot.com");
myArray[3].setPropertyValue("company", "HubSpot");
myArray[4].setPropertyValue("phone", "555-122-2323");
myArray[5].setPropertyValue("address", "25 First Street");
myArray[6].setPropertyValue("city", "HCambridge");
myArray[7].setPropertyValue("state", "MA");
myArray[8].setPropertyValue("zip", "02139");
}

public static class Property //Properties object {
public String property;//attributes
public String value;

//General Constructor
public Property(String property, String value){
this.property = property;
this.value = value;
}
//getter method
public String getPropertyValue() {
return this.property+" : "+this.value;
}
//setter method
public void setPropertyValue(String property, String value) {
this.property = property;
this.value = value;
}}}
```

I'm using this JSON file, which I tried to put into Java Objects:

{
    "properties": 
**[**
   {
    "property": "firstname",
    "value": "HubSpot"
    },
    {
    "property": "lastname",
    "value": "Test"
    },
    {
    "property": "website",
    "value": "http:// hubspot.com"
    },
    {
    "property": "company",
    "value": "HubSpot"
    },
    {
    "property": "phone",
    "value": "555-122-2323"
    },
    {
    "property": "address",
    "value": "25 First Street"
    },
    {
    "property": "city",
    "value": "Cambridge"
    },
    {
    "property": "state",
      "value": "MA"
    },
    {
    "property": "zip",
    "value": "02139"
    }
    **]**
    }

**edit**

I've renamed my Class to MyGsonTest, imported com.google.gson.Gson instead of com.google.gson.* and fixed my array initialization. However, '.toJson' method is still not working. 
This is the tutorial I was using as an example and the method I'm having trouble with seems to work just fine there: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ou2yFJ-NWr8&index=2&list=PLpUMhvC6l7AOy4UEORSutzFus98n-Es_l

Comment: `public static String serializeJson(ParentObject obj1) {     
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(obj1);
}`  this code will not compile as it needs to return a `String`

Comment: You are right! Thanks! I added the return statement in my code.

Comment: Sorry, but when you edit your question, then dont just **add** some more information in the end. Really **rework** the question. If you renamed your class from Gson to MyGsonTest, then please: update the corresponding source code. You want to make sure that somebody can look at *only* the question content, and quickly understand what you are asking.  Here, one would have to study all the comments, all the answers, and the comments there, and it is still confusing what exactly your problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you are importing from the GSON jar is probably being overwritten by your own class called `Gson`

```
public class Gson {
```

The reason that `gson.toJson(obj1);` does not exist is the your have not written any such method.

The class you are wanting to use is `com.google.gson.Gson`, so I suggest for a start to rename your own hand crafted class to something else e.g. `MyGSonTest`

As per [Apache Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) *Apache Maven is a software project management and comprehension tool.*

**edit**

Also regarding your Array problem, you need to declare the Array with a size

```
Property [] myArray = new Property[10];
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I changed the class name and fixed my array initialisation. I've also imported com.google.gson.Gson instead. Regarding 'toJson' method, is it not a built in method of Gson library? [link] (https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html)

Comment: Yes, it does seem to be a method of `com.google.gson.Gson` but in your code, `Gson` was referring to your own code. If you still not working, then please edit your question, appending what you have tried

Comment: *appending what you have tried* - you have totally changed your question, and therefore my answer looks irrelevant.  **PLUS** the code that you have posted will not even compile

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so I had three questions. I've figured out what I was doing wrong.

**Question 1.** Gson jar works fine. There is nothing else needed for it to work other than building a path to it in your project and importing com.google.gson.Gson library as *Scary Wombat* pointed out.

**Question 2.** The error I kept getting with the toJson method was because the method was not called correctly. It's working as expected when it's called like this:

```
String json = new Gson().toJson(obj1);
```

**Question 3.**
Initially I had an array of Objects. I had to change it to an ArrayList, so I'm able to add Objects to it, instead of having to declare an array of fixed size.

I had to change my Classes too. I will post the correct code below. This code creates Java classes that are then used to save the data you create in those classes in JSON format.

Hope this helps in case anybody's having the same issue.

Main class:

```
package myGsonTestPackage;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class MyGsonTest {
public static void main(String args[]) {        
serialize();        
}   
private static void serialize() {
ParentObject obj1 = new ParentObject();
//initialize 9 Property Objects as per Json file we're working with 
Property p1 = new Property();
Property p2 = new Property();
Property p3 = new Property();
Property p4 = new Property();
Property p5 = new Property();
Property p6 = new Property();
Property p7 = new Property();
Property p8 = new Property();
Property p9 = new Property();

//set property and value for each Property Object we've initialized
p1.setPropertyValue("firstname", "HubSpot");
p2.setPropertyValue("lastname", "Test");
p3.setPropertyValue("website", "http://hubspot.com");
p4.setPropertyValue("company", "HubSpot");
p5.setPropertyValue("phone", "555-122-2323");
p6.setPropertyValue("address", "25 First Street");
p7.setPropertyValue("city", "HCambridge");
p8.setPropertyValue("state", "MA");
p9.setPropertyValue("zip", "02139");

//Populate the ArrayList
obj1.properties.add(p1);
obj1.properties.add(p2);
obj1.properties.add(p3);
obj1.properties.add(p4);
obj1.properties.add(p5);
obj1.properties.add(p6);
obj1.properties.add(p7);
obj1.properties.add(p8);
obj1.properties.add(p9);
//create Json representation of the data
String json = new Gson().toJson(obj1);
//Print the data
System.out.println(json);
}}
```

ParentObject Class:

```
package myGsonTestPackage;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class ParentObject {
public ArrayList<Property> properties = new ArrayList<>(); }
```

Property Class:

```
package myGsonTestPackage;
public class Property {
public String property;//attributes
public String value;

//getter method
public String getPropertyValue() {
return this.property+" : "+this.value;
}
//setter method
public void setPropertyValue(String property, String value) {
this.property = property;
this.value = value;
}}
```

Comment: `Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(obj1);` is the same as `String json = new Gson().toJson(obj1);` - your answer does not add anything that my post did not answer.  Really I expected you to accept my answer as is the StackOverflow way.

Comment: The thing is when I write this:
    Gson gson = new Gson(); String json = gson.toJson(obj1);
I get a compile error. So,it seems like it's not the same in this particular case. I did took your advice and changed the name that was probably conflicting with other things in my code, but it hasn't fixed the issue I was having. I posted the full code as I had other questions as well and changed my code quite a bit. I'm sorry if you felt like your help was not appreciated. This was not my intention.